# Configure url path in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this. I am trying to configure the url for the base application, and I just cannot figure out where this is done at.

I want to call it Routing, but I know that this isn't the correct words, so let me do a bit of explanation on what I'm trying to do. We got a template for an MVC application that allowed us to add angular 2 into the app, works great from Visual Studio, we deploy in IIS  into its own web site it works. We move it to the default website it no longer works.

With all of that said now I can explain what the issue is,
the browser is getting to the application at `localhost/Test/` but when it is trying to download the `app.component.ts` all of the others, it then is trying to goto `localhost/app/app.component.js` not `localhost/Test/app/app.component`. Now my questions: where do i configure the url to go to localhost.**Test**/app...?

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { GenerateComponent } from './components/generate/generate.component';
import { NewuserComponent } from './components/newuser/newuser.component';
import { NewlocationComponent } from './components/newlocation/newlocation.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'generate', component: GenerateComponent },
    { path: 'newuser', component: NewuserComponent },
    { path: 'newlocation', component: NewlocationComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders =
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Post your routes file.   Also, run through https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Thank you what the issue was is that we didn't have a redirect to.

Comment: Do you use angular-cli?

Comment: yes, I did use cli

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `deploy-url` option on angular-cli.

[Check the docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

You can do it as follows

For `serve` command `ng serve --deploy-url /test/`

For `build` command `ng build --deploy-url /test/`

Comment: Doesn't work - I'm getting the following Error-Message: `Unknown option: '-d'
Unknown option: '/projectName/'
`

Comment: @FlixRo that answer was from 2 years ago. Angular-cli has changed, I've updated my answer